# How to encrypt a (USB) Thumb / Flash Drive in Ubuntu 14.4

Tags: usb, encryption

This question has been asked before but it has not been properly answered.  I am not able to comment on that site and so ask the question again.  When I try: "sudo apt-get install gnome-disk-utility" it is not installed - probably because it (Disk Utility) is no longer available - it seems to have been "upgraded" to "Disks" - which does not offer encryption.
A solution would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a package in Ubuntu called `ecryptfs` which will give you a nice portable encryption option for your USB stick.

The following is a snippet from the [ubuntu server guide ecryptfs](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/ecryptfs.html) tutorial

### Using eCryptfs

First, install the necessary packages. From a terminal prompt enter:

```
sudo apt-get install ecryptfs-utils
```

Now mount the partition to be encrypted:

```
sudo mount -t ecryptfs /srv /srv
```

You will then be prompted for some details on how ecryptfs should encrypt the data.

To test that files placed in /srv are indeed encrypted copy the `/etc/default` folder to `/srv`:

```
sudo cp -r /etc/default /srv
```

Now unmount /srv, and try to view a file:

```
sudo umount /srv
cat /srv/default/cron
```

Remounting /srv using ecryptfs will make the data viewable once again.

Comment: Many thanks LP - much appreciated.  Sincerely, Duncan

Answer (score 2):

There are several options, encrypt just some files with eCryptfs or EncFS, or a whole partition or drive with dm-crypt/LUKS (very similar to TrueCrypt, in fact cryptsetup can open (most?) TrueCrypt devices).

See [archlinux's informative wiki about disk encryption](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Disk_encryption).

---

LUKS encrypts entire partitions/drives, and should be installed by default on recent Ubuntu's.

If your USB drive is for example partitioned as `/dev/sdn1`, to encrypt it you would run :

```
sudo cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sdn1
```

then decrypt it:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdn1 crypt1
```

format it with (for example ext):
    sudo mke2fs /dev/mapper/crypt1

then just mount & use it. When done unmount & `sudo cryptsetup luksClose crypt1`

Comment: No problem, just have to decide if you want to encrypt a whole partition or just some files. I'll add in an other link & bit more info too

Comment: Thanks once again Xen - much appreciated.  I might come back to you as I am having trouble getting it to work - but will battle on for a few days before hassling you.  If I did come back to you should I do it through this thread or somehow else?  Thanks once again - don't know what I would do without the help one can get here. Duncan